# Why can't you accept more than one answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, reputation

especially on this site it is sometimes very much about experiences and I have e.g. in my last [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29590/when-bikepacking-solo-how-to-handle-luggage-when-shopping) many great answers (there isnt a single right answer but at the same time there isnt a wrong answer), I would like to accept more than one answer as correct or helpful (so that the person who writes this gets a reward +15). My suggestion would be to set this up but to prevent that you only accept all answers for the +2 reputation even if you choose multiple correct answers you only get +2 once. This means that the people who make the effort to write great answers (which also partly build on each other) are rewarded. Would this be possible?

Comment: I think this belongs on the Stack Exchange wide meta, as it is something that is dictated by the whole Stack Exchange structure. I do not see an option to move it there for you.

Comment: Do you think its worth to ask?

Comment: I think the current answer will be no but it might make changes possible in the future. And I can be wrong on either count.

Answer (score 2):

You can only accept one - this is by design, and it should be the answer you found most useful.

If you want to also reward other posters, you can assign a bounty - which gives them rep directly.